# print xml text on browser in php

Tags: php

Having a directory full of images, now I want to print something like following xml lines in php browser

```
<image>
    <thumb_path>amor/thumbs/1_cuadro_de_amor.jpg</thumb_path>
    <image_path>amor/1_cuadro_de_amor.jpg</image_path>
    <transition_type>swipe_from_left_to_right</transition_type>
    <transition_duration>1</transition_duration>
    <transition_delay>3</transition_delay>
    <description_window from="left" to_x="55" to_y="0" duration="1" delay="0"><![CDATA[<p class="descRed1_1">1.- Cuadro de amor</p>]]></description_window>
  </image>
```

So I created a php file and uploaded it

```
$dir = 'amor';
$count=1;
foreach (glob($dir.'/*.*') as $filename)
{
    if($filename=="." || $filename==".." || $filename=="download.php" || $filename=="index.php")
    {
        //this will not display specified files
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'header ("Content-Type:text/xml");';
        echo '<image>';
        echo '  <thumb_path>'.$dir.'/thumbs/'.$filename.'</thumb_path>';
        echo '  <image_path>'.$dir.'/"'.$filename.'</image_path>';
        echo '  <transition_type>swipe_from_left_to_right</transition_type>';
        echo '  <transition_duration>1</transition_duration>';
        echo '  <transition_delay>3</transition_delay>';
        echo '  <description_window from="left" to_x="55" to_y="0" duration="1" delay="0"><![CDATA[<p class="descRed1_1">'.$count.'.- "'.ucfirst(str_replace("_"," ",$filename)).'</p>]]></description_window>';
        echo "</image>";
        echo "<br>";
        $count++;
    }
}
```

However xml tags are not displaying  correctly, What am I missing
I tried adding

```
echo 'header ("Content-Type:text/xml");';
```

but did not work

I am getting 
amor/thumbs/amor/1_cuadro_de_amor.jpg amor/"amor/1_cuadro_de_amor.jpg swipe_from_left_to_right 1 3 1.- "Amor/10 cuadro de alegra.jpg

]]>

also how do I get rid of dir string on filename, in this case "amor"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the 'echo' part of that statement. You just want

header("Content-Type:text/xml") ;

You might want to put this at the top as well:

Make sure that there is no whitespace before the first xml tag or you will get an error.

Comment: Ok that worked, however I have 2 issues, how to add a new line ? I tried `<br>` and `\n` but it says it is bad formed xml, and also how to get rid of "amor" in `"amor/$filename"`